# Change an HTML <p> tag value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have an HTML form that allows a user to type in the name of a faction and submit it with a button:

```
<form method="get">
    </br><button type="submit" onclick="createFaction()">create faction</button>
    <input placeholder="name" id="factionName" name="factionName"></input>
</form>
```

The reason it is [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) at the moment is purely for testing.

I then have a JavaScript function that changes the name of this:

```
<p id="test1"></p>
```

to whatever the users input was. The JavaScript code is

```
function createFaction() {
    var name = document.getElementById('factionName'),
    factionName = input.value;

    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = name;
}
```

However, it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Your button is a "submit" button, which means it causes the form to be submitted and the page to be reloaded with the response. Make it `type=button` instead.

Comment: that doesn't work either

Comment: Also, the function is wrong; you fetch the `<input>` element into the variable "name" but then refer to "input.name" in that assignment statement; that'll cause an error. You need to keep your browser developer console open while debugging.

Comment: how would I fix the function?

Comment: Ah I've fixed it now

Answer (score 9):

First change `type='button'`. Instead use submit, `type="submit"`. It will submit the page and you will not see changes done. The change is here:

```
<button type="button" onclick="createFaction()">create faction</button>
```

Then change `name.value` in JavaScript to get the value from the `name` object:

```
factionName = name.value;
```

```js
function createFaction() {
    var name = document.getElementById('factionName'),
    factionName = name.value;

    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = factionName;
}
```

```html
<form method="get">
    </br><button type="button" onclick="createFaction()">create faction</button>
    <input placeholder="name" id="factionName" name="factionName">
    </form>
<p id="test1"></p>
```

Another way to do this is,

```js
function createFaction(faction) {
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = faction;
}
```

```html
<input onchange="createFaction(this.value)" onkeyup="createFaction(this.value)" placeholder="type something ..." id="factionName" name="factionName">
<p id="test1"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

*onclick* will fire with button type = *submit* and the function will look like:

```
function createFaction() {
    var name = document.getElementById('factionName').value;
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a form for this, and also the function can be made simpler - just do it this way:

```js
function createFaction() {
  var name = document.getElementById('factionName').value;
  document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = name;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createFaction()">create faction</button>
<input placeholder="name" id="factionName" name="factionName"></input>

<p id="test1"></p>
```

Comment: What's the point in jQuery if there are just 2 lines of JS that will do the same work? Is it browsers compatibility issue? There should be a reason. What am I missing?

Comment: @Axalix The question contained the jQuery tag, so I included it at first and simply forgot to take it out again. I removed it now- works as well...

Comment: I see. I think the tag is irrelevant to a question, since there are no references.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap this into a `form` since you are not trying to send data to a server, so you can just skip it.
Also I would use [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) for this:

```
<button id="factionBtn">create faction</button>
<input placeholder="name" id="factionName" name="factionName">
<p id="test1"></p>
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function createFaction() {
  var $paragraph   = $('#test1');
  var $factionName = $('#factionName');

  $('#factionBtn').click(function(e) {
    console.log($factionName.val());
    $paragraph.text($factionName.val());
  });
});
```